# How to scrape HTML table into google sheets

Tags: html, google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, yahoo-finance

I would like to extract the Forward Dividend from a site such as Yahoo Finance and insert it into Google Sheets.

Example 1:
For ticker symbol AAPL: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL
I would like the the Google Sheet field to return: 0.82

Example 2:
For the same symbol: https://www.streetinsider.com/dividend_history.php?q=aapl
I would like it to return the 0.82 amount from the table.

Is this even possible?

Comment: "Is this even possible?" - yes, but it'd involve **a lot of steps** and this question will likely be closed for being too broad. How would you be running this script, exactly? A Chrome extension would work, I suppose.

Comment: If you want to get the numeric value of a table cell in an in-page script, that's trivial: `var value = parseFloat( document.querySelector( 'table#tableId > tbody > tr:nth-child(123) > td:nth-child(456)' ).textContent )`.

Comment: The broadness comes from the technology you'll be using, e.g. selenium (java, c#, javascript), a client e.g. new HttpClient()... or will you using as Dai said a chrome extension(javascript). It's possible, isn't that hard.. but it really comes down to what experience you have and more comfortable with.

Comment: I am using a Chrome web browser for the Google Sheet. I find it impossible to extract that value.
The "var value" thing needs to point to one of the links in order to work.
A while ago, I was using: =IMPORTXML("https://old.nasdaq.com/symbol/"&B2&"/dividend-history","//*[@id='quotes_content_left_dividendhistoryGrid_CashAmount_0']")
But that site doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned you want to use the built-in `IMPORT*` functions, I will answer from that perspective.

As with most Sheets-based scraping, it depends on the site. The two sites you have given behave very differently. Let's examine them separately:

### 1: Yahoo Finance - Possible

We view source and see that 0.82 is located in a table. This lets us use `IMPORTHTML`:

```
=INDEX(
    SPLIT(
        VLOOKUP(
            "Forward Dividend & Yield",
            IMPORTHTML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL", "table", 2),
            2,
        ),
        " "
    ),
    1
)
```

1. Import table data
2. Get the dividend row
3. Extract the dividend yield value.

### 2: Street Insider - Not Possible

You might think that since the View Source lets us see the table in the browser, we should be able to use `IMPORTHTML()` again. Sadly this is not the case. The server-side seems to detect that you're not using a browser to access the `.php`, and it will display an empty page. Google sheets uses a different user agent from your own browser.

The only thing I can recommend if you need to use the `IMPORT*` functions is that you find a different site to pull the data from.

Comment: Now it doesn't work anymore... it displays #N/A.
Do you know why that is? It worked for just 1 day...

Comment: @Tommy No idea. Still working for me. You can mouseover the #N/A to see what's wrong.

Comment: Error
Did not find value 'Forward Dividend & Yield' in VLOOKUP evaluation.

No idea what that means

Comment: @Tommy It means that whatever table got imported doesn't have the value in the first column. Does just the `IMPORTHTML` give you any data? It may be that you have to lookup a different value and index to get the right value. Web scraping is always shaky business.

Comment: Also, I am writing it like below, where B2 = ticker symbol = AAPL

=INDEX(
    SPLIT(
        VLOOKUP(
            "Forward Dividend & Yield",
            IMPORTHTML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"&B2, "table", 2),
            2,
        ),
        " "
    ),
    1
)

Comment: Error
Imported content is empty. (for the IMPORTHTML)

Comment: In another sheet it works just fine. When I do multiple (30) "scrapes", some of them get error.
Nevermind, I give up, I'll do them manually. This is too much work for little gain.
Thanks anyways, you've been very helpful and nice about it.

Comment: @Tommy Yeah, sorry about that... scraping is very hacky and Sheets Formulas don't give you great tools to deal with errors.